# $('select').material_select() is not a function - initialising Materializecss select field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, materialize

I'm using Materializecss with React and I'm trying to initialise the select field dynamically using:

```
$('select').material_select()
```

but I get an error that
**TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function**

I doing this because I'm populating the values in the select field dynamically and the values do not show in the select dropdown sometimes. It's inconsistent. sometimes the values show and some other times the values don't show in the material select dropdown.

Samples from my code is below:
I have included jquery and materialize in the index.html file

in the component I have the following:

```
const $ = require('jquery');

componentDidMount(){

$('select').material_select();

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I've spent quite sometime trying to resolve this.

**Edited**

I seem to have a solution now that seems to work for me. after including jquery as above, I changed the material select line to:

```
window.$('select').material_select();
```

and used it just after loading my values into the options tag of the select field. I didn't need to call it in componentDidMount any longer.

I also destroyed the material select in componentWillUnmount. (not sure if it's necessary though).

```
   componentWillUnmount(){
    $('select').material_select('destroy');
 }
```

Comment: Have you added materialize.js?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've resolved the issue now. I change the line to window.$('select').material_select() and used it just after loading the values into the select option tags. I didn't need to call it in componentDidMount any longer. This seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks @TirthPatel.